# Reusing a Mustache template from another one, if both are defined in one html file

Tags: javascript, mustache

How can invoke and use one template from another one if both are defined within separate  tags inthe same html file?

I know that this is certainly possible with different .mustache files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to use partials that are defined in the same HTML file as the templates. This example uses the same partial in two separate templates to demonstrate that. Please let me know if you were looking for a different example.

Here are two different templates and one partial

```js
<script type=text id=tpl1>
    {{greeting}} {{> planet}}
</script>

<script type=text id=tpl2>
    {{planet}}
</script>

<script type=text id=tpl3>
    {{> planet}} {{goal}}
</script>​
```

Here is the JavaScript to find these templates, prepare their data, and render with the reused partial.

```js
// get template html
var tpl1 = $('#tpl1').html(),
    tpl2 = $('#tpl2').html(), // partial
    tpl3 = $('#tpl3').html(),
// define data for each template
    tpl1Data = { 'greeting' : 'hello'},
    tpl2Data = { 'planet' : 'world'},
    tpl3Data = { 'goal' : 'peace'},
// define partial object
    partial = {'planet' : tpl2 },
// render to html combining template view and partial view and defining partial
    html1 = Mustache.to_html(tpl1, jQuery.extend(tpl1Data, tpl2Data), partial),
    html2 = Mustache.to_html(tpl3, jQuery.extend(tpl3Data, tpl2Data), partial);
// write compiled Mustache templates to document
document.write(html1 + ', let\'s try for ' + html2);
```

​You can [see this example in its working entirety on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/xMPf6/).

If you wanted to use different data for the partial in the second template, you could just define something like `tpl2bData = { 'planet' : 'mars' }` and reference it when rendering `html2`.

```
html2 = Mustache.to_html(tpl3, jQuery.extend(tpl3Data, tpl2bData), partial);
```